# Error when i open an link genetared by pentaho server

Tags: pentaho

Failed to process the report.

Failed to evaluate formula-expression y with error Encountered "=" at line 1, column 1.

Was expecting one of:

<UNSIGNED_INTEGER> ...

"(" ...

"{" ...

"+" ...

"-" ...

...

<COLUMN_LOOKUP> ...

<STRING_LITERAL> ...

<UNSIGNED_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...

"null" ...

.

Encountered "=" at line 1, column 1.

Was expecting one of:

<UNSIGNED_INTEGER> ...

"(" ...

"{" ...

"+" ...

"-" ...

...

<COLUMN_LOOKUP> ...

<STRING_LITERAL> ...

<UNSIGNED_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...

"null" ...

. what is this error and how do i resolve this

i expected the link to generate a report but got above error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't start your formula in the formula step like you are used to in Excel or any comparable software with an "=" sign. Just leave the starting "=" sign out. The field already knows it is expecting a formula. So for example not `=IF(...)` but just `IF(...)`